# How can I improve the speed of hundreds of pandas .loc calls on 1M rows of data?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of about 1M rows and growing. I need to do multiple case-insensitive look-ups in a column, and assign a different value to another column if it is found. The current way I'm accomplishing this is:

```
df.loc[df.columnA.str.contains('(?i)^match_string', na=False, regex=True), 'columnB'] = 'New Value'
```

So it's looking in `columnA` for anything that **starts with** the `match_string`, **case insensitive**, then if it is found, it assigns the `New Value` to `columnB`.

The problem is that I need to do this several hundred times, and it's really slow. I've considered using `.at` instead of `.loc`, but my impression is that you can only use `.at` for looking up a single value, and I need to find any and all instances of the `match_string` (that is, `match_string` could occur in multiple rows of a `columnA`). Am I wrong--can I use .at here?

What's the fastest way to go about this? It's currently taking over an hour, and it's just going to get worse as the dataframe grows.

Comment: The problem is not `loc`, but rather the `str.contains()` part.

Comment: i was facing the same issue. I used .iat instead of iloc and loc and that increased the speed of my process significantly

Comment: Do you have to reprocess the DataFrame while it is growing? Sounds like you could store the last index/size processed, and process from there.

Comment: @QuangHoang interesting, do you have a suggestion for a better method I could use instead of `str.contains()`?

Comment: @Vikika for some reason I thought I couldn't use .iat to identify multiple rows. My match_string could match more than one row. Will it still work in this case?

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? Is there any relation between the strings to match and the value to assign, for example?

Comment: @AMC The context is name cleaning. I'm looking for a slight misspelling of the beginning of a name (company name, say), and then assigning the correct spelling. So if the correct company name is `Google, Inc.` but my data has lots of `Gogle, Inc.`, the match_string would be `gogle` and I would assign Google, Inc. to columnB. Btw, I'm transitioning an existing SAS codebase to Python, so all of the matches are pre-written, I'm just trying to find a faster way to iterate through it.

Comment: @EnsAndBees How many strings are there to match? Will each row only match a single string? What else is in your DataFrame?

Comment: @AMC There are hundreds of distinct strings to match, hence the hundreds of .loc (and .contains) calls. A single match_string can match multiple rows. My dataframe also contains about 10-15 other columns.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few hints that could help you to improve processing

1) Create a new column columnC that clones columnA but lowercased.
And then, of course, make sure you use a lowercased match_string
This will avoid the case insensitive search.

2) You can even create your columnC with a substring of columnA : the Nth first chars, N being the length of match_string.

These 2 points will help you to reduce your regexp problem to basic string comparison rather than regular expression execution.
Regexp evaluation is **not** pattern matching. Well, it can be one way to use regular expressions, but it creates an automaton for each regular expression you want to apply.

Also, when you use the same regex again and again, you should instantiate a single matcher class and reuse it instead of "contains". This is similar to code compilation, but for regexps.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! #1 might work for me. But one of my issues is that each of the hundreds of .loc/.str.contains statements uses a *different* match_string. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my OP.

Comment: You can still apply option 1 and then compare substrings - still faster than regexp